# Jquery Pie chart with inner circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

For an project i need to realise an chart with two circles. It need to looks like this one:

[image]

Is there an Jquery solution that support this? I already tried with Jqplot but with that plug-in i can't succeed to create something like this. I tried with this code:

```
// Create chart
var plot1 = $.jqplot('pie_chart', [s2,s1], {
seriesDefaults: {
  renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
  rendererOptions:{
    startAngle: -90,
    showDataLabels: true,               
    dataLabels: 'value',    
    innerDiameter :0,
    padding:5,
    highlightMouseOver:false
  }
}
});

//Theming based in the rendered module items in the HTML
temp = {
seriesStyles: {seriesColors: array2},
    grid: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        borderWidth: 0,
        shadow: false
    }
};        

plot1.themeEngine.newTheme('uma', temp);
plot1.activateTheme('uma');
```

But the colors are for the inner and outer ring the same and create something like this:

[image]

The settings for the style are for the inner and outer ring. In my case i need to give the outer ring an different style.

Can i use this plug-in or do i need to use an other Jquery plug-in to realise my chart?

Comment: Changed my questions and made it more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution wich works with d3.js (http://d3js.org/):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423

Works fine for me! Currently looks like this:

[image]